# I have a drop down list inside a repeater , But i dont know how to catch each dropdown selectindexchange event and run server side code for it

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mapping

**this where i populate the repeater Textbox with old column name from csv file and DDL from the columns available to map**

```
  public void PopulateStep2Grid(List<string> fileColumnsNames, DataTable table)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    var repeaterItems = Step2Grid.Controls.OfType<RepeaterItem>().ToList();
                    foreach (var Column in fileColumnsNames)
                    {

                        var item = repeaterItems[index];
                        SourceTextBox = item.FindControl("txtSourceColumnNames") as TextBox;
                        ReguiredColumnDDl = item.FindControl("RequiredColumnDDL") as DropDownList;
                        if (SourceTextBox != null && ReguiredColumnDDl != null)
                        {
                            SourceTextBox.Text = Column;
                            ReguiredColumnDDl.DataSource = table.Columns;
                            ReguiredColumnDDl.DataBind();
                            ReguiredColumnDDl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select required Column that map source column", "NA"));
                            ReguiredColumnDDl.ClientID.
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }


 on selected index change i want to map this particular value of dropdownlist and text box asseigned next to drop down list and save them in dictionary so the out is 
    (value of old column )(value of new column name that user choose from DDL
```

protected void ReguiredColumnDDl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        Mapping(this.SourceTextBox, this.ReguiredColumnDDl);
                    }

```
    *************************************************************************
     public Dictionary<string, string> Mapping(TextBox source, DropDownList hlcolumns)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> columnmapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    string value = source.Text;
                    string newvalue = string.Empty;
                    switch (hlcolumns.SelectedValue)
                    {

                        case "Bio":
                            newvalue = "Bio";
                            break;
                        case "IsOrganization":
                            newvalue = "IsOrganization";
                            break;

                        case "IsActive":
                            newvalue = "IsActive";
                            break;
                        case "ExcludeFromDirectory":
                            newvalue = "ExcludeFromDirectory";
                            break;


                        case "ParentMemberKey":
                            newvalue = "ParentMemberKey";
                            break;
                        case "Title":
                            newvalue = "Title";
                            break;

                        case "CompanyName":
                            newvalue = "CompanyName";
                            break;
                        case "SuffixCode":
                            newvalue = "SuffixCode";
                            break;

                        case "Gender":
                            newvalue = "Gender";
                            break;
                        case "InformalName":
                            newvalue = "InformalName";
                            break;

                        case "LastName":
                            newvalue = "LastName";
                            break;
                        case "MiddleName":
                            newvalue = "MiddleName";
                            break;
                        case "FirstName":
                            newvalue = "FirstName";
                            break;
                        case "PrefixCode":
                            newvalue = "PrefixCode";
                            break;

                        case "EmailAddress":
                            newvalue = "EmailAddress";
                            break;
                        case "Designation":
                            newvalue = "Designation";
                            break;

                        case "Age":
                            newvalue = "Age";
                            break;
                        case "State":
                            newvalue = "State";
                            break;
                        case "PostalCode":
                            newvalue = "PostalCode";
                            break;

                        case "Country":
                            newvalue = "Country";
                            break;
                        case "City":
                            newvalue = "City";
                            break;
                        case "Address3":
                            newvalue = "Address3";
                            break;
                        case "Address2":
                            newvalue = "Address2";
                            break;

                        case "Address1":
                            newvalue = "Address1";
                            break;
                        case "Phone4Type":
                            newvalue = "Phone4Type";
                            break;
                        case "Phone4":
                            newvalue = "Phone4";
                            break;
                        case "Phone3Type":
                            newvalue = "Phone3Type";
                            break;

                        case "Phone3":
                            newvalue = "Phone3";
                            break;
                        case "Phone2Type":
                            newvalue = "Phone2Type";
                            break;
                        case "Phone2":
                            newvalue = "Phone2";
                            break;
                        case "Phone1Type":
                            newvalue = "Phone1Type";
                            break;

                        case "Phone1":
                            newvalue = "Phone1";
                            break;
                        case "WebsiteUrl":
                            newvalue = "WebsiteUrl";
                            break;

                        case "LegacyContactKey":
                            newvalue = "LegacyContactKey";
                            break;
                        case "MemberBadgeKey":
                            newvalue = "MemberBadgeKey";
                            break;

                        case "Password":
                            newvalue = "Password";
                            break;
                        case "PrimaryContactLegacyContactKey":
                            newvalue = "PrimaryContactLegacyContactKey";
                            break;
                        case "Birthday":
                            newvalue = "Birthday";
                            break;
                        case "MemberId":
                            newvalue = "MemberId";
                            break;

                        case "Ethnicity":
                            newvalue = "Ethnicity";
                            break;
                        case "ProfileImageURL":
                            newvalue = "ProfileImageURL";
                            break;

                        case "OtherBlogURL":
                            newvalue = "OtherBlogURL";
                            break;
                        case "BloggerURL":
                            newvalue = "BloggerURL";
                            break;

                        case "WordPressURL":
                            newvalue = "WordPressURL";
                            break;
                        case "LinkedInURL":
                            newvalue = "LinkedInURL";
                            break;
                        case "GooglePlusURL":
                            newvalue = "GooglePlusURL";
                            break;
                        case "TwitterURL":
                            newvalue = "TwitterURL";
                            break;

                        case "FaceBookURL":
                            newvalue = "FaceBookURL";
                            break;
                        case "YouTubeURL":
                            newvalue = "YouTubeURL";
                            break;
                        default:
                            newvalue = string.Empty;
                            break;
                    }
                    columnmapping.Add(value, newvalue);
                    return columnmapping;

                }
```

**Thanks in Advance please help**

Comment: Why do you need a switch/case here. Can't you just set the newvalue to selected dropdowllist value and add it to columnmapping dictionary ?

Comment: Did you remember to set:  `AutoPostBack="True"` on the DDL?